# Выдает ошибку C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(' '); 
string selectedWord = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); //  System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
int count = 0;

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.Trim() == selectedWord.Trim()) 
    {
        count++;
    }
}

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Количество найденных слов: " + count;
```

}

Ввести в компонентCombobox  3 слова из текста  компонента TextBox, наиболее часто встречающихся. Написать обработчик события нажатия кнопки Найти для проверки наличия выбранного в Combobox слова в строках компонента TextBox. Подсчитать количество найденных  слов  в тексте TextBox и вывести это значение в строке состояния

Comment: `Выдает ошибку C# Winforms` какую и где?

Comment: string selectedWord = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();                   
 System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: `string selectedWord = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` ==> `string selectedWord = comboBox1.SelectedItem?.ToString()?.Trim();`

Comment: `if (word.Trim() == selectedWord.Trim())` ==> `if (word.Trim() == selectedWord)`